# Selenium in headless mode with Flask and Celery throws WebDriverException: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, celery

I am trying to run Selenium in headless mode within a Flask app and using Celery tasks. When I execute my script, I get the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127
```

Here is a minimal working example of my code:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from celery import Celery
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = os.getenv('CELERY_BROKER_URL')
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = os.getenv('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND')

celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)

@celery.task
def run_selenium_task(referral_id, comment):
    # Insert your Selenium script here

@app.route('/run_selenium', methods=['POST'])
def run_selenium():
    referral_id = request.form['referral_id']
    comment = request.form['comment']
    run_selenium_task.delay(referral_id, comment)
    return 'Selenium task started'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Selenium script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("-headless")
firefox_binary_path = '/usr/bin/firefox'
geckodriver_path = '/home/fusion/bin/geckodriver'
options.binary_location = firefox_binary_path
service = Service(executable_path=geckodriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

# Insert the rest of your Selenium code here
```

What am I missing, and how can I fix this issue to run Selenium with Flask and Celery in headless mode without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one

```
option.add_argument("--headless=new") 
option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--window-size=1920, 1080")
option.add_argument("user-agent= Chrome/111.0.5563.64")--> need to update firefox here
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
option.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')    
prefs = {"download.default_directory": finalPath}
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
"download.default_directory": finalPath,
"download.prompt_for_download": False,
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
"safebrowsing.enabled": False
}
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).